# exporting tables to excel sheet in jsp

Tags: excel, jsp

how can i export my table to excel sheet in jsp??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a HTML table and send this HTML with the following response headers:

```
Content-type = application/vnd.ms-excel
Content-disposition = attachment;filename=whateverIsAppropriate.xls
```

Another option would be to create the Excel using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org) and then send that as the response.